# Editing the EditText context menu in Android

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-edittext

Is there a way to add a custom case to the existing context menu in Android? We all have a context menu that is called on the active `EditText` view, the one with "Input Type" and other. What I need is to add another case to this menu, say "Options". I honestly searched for info on [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#FloatingContextMenu), but no luck over there. They only write about creating your own menu from scratch. I don't need to change it systemwide as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967348/is-it-possible-to-add-some-item-in-the-context-menus-of-android-system-menu) does. My only concern is to change it in one activity of my app, one instance of `EditText`to be precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7383161/1351347

It is NOT possible to override the system-wide contextMenu. You could (as you already know) push another contextMenu on a longClick on this single EditText.

Comment: I asked that question, you beat me by a few seconds here =p

Comment: Problem is, I don't need to change it systemwide. I need to change only one menu in my app. Example you linked is again concerning the systemwide/inter-app alterations.

Comment: But I got the idea, that even in your own app you need to override the menu with your own and add all of the default options manually, right?